# How to update 2 tables using triggers

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have 2 tables,

- lv_data,

It has the following fields,

```
              emp_name            tot_days 
                guru                18
```

- leave_data

it has the following fields,

```
       emp_name   From_date      to_date       no_of_days   remaining_days 
           guru   02/05/2012     03/05/2012         2
```

In second table if the data is inserted, the `no_of_days` will be automatically calculated `(from to_date - From_date)+1`

Here I need to write the trigger to update the remaining_days column,

In first table for all `emp_name`, `tot_days` is 18 days, so in second table whenever the record is inserted,  the `remaining_days` should be calculated like this

```
remaining_days := tot_days - no_of_days
```

And this(calculated) value should be updated in `tot_days` column in first table(`lv_data`),

Sample Example:

```
        emp_name tot_days 
          guru     18
```

- leave_data

  ```
  emp_name     From_date    to_date        no_of_days   remaining_days 
  guru        02/05/2012    03/05/2012        2            16
  ```

Now the first table should be updated like,

```
     emp_name tot_days 
        guru     16
```

So I need to update 2 tables. Can someone help me to update these 2 tables through trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Have an before insert trigger on the table which will set the record before inserting it

Few things to note:

- Your data model doesn't have a unique identifier for a row
- I don't think your "no_of_days" calculation is right.

---

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER leave_data_before_insert
  BEFORE INSERT ON LEAVE_DATA
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_lv_data(
      p_emp_id IN lv_data.id%TYPE) IS
      SELECT tot_days
      FROM   lv_data
      WHERE  id = p_emp_id;
    v_tot_days NUMBER;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_lv_data(:new.id);

    FETCH c_lv_data INTO v_tot_days;

    :new.no_of_days := ( :new.from_date - :new.TO_DATE ) + 1;

    :new.remaining_days := v_tot_days - :new.no_of_days;

    UPDATE lv_data
    SET    tot_days = :new.remaining_days
    WHERE  id = :new.id;

    CLOSE c_lv_data;
END;
```

DDL used to test:

```
CREATE TABLE lv_data
  (
     id       NUMBER,
     emp_name VARCHAR2(240),
     tot_days NUMBER
  );

CREATE TABLE leave_data
  (
     id             NUMBER,
     emp_name       VARCHAR2(240),
     from_date      DATE,
     to_date        DATE,
     no_of_days     NUMBER,
     remaining_days NUMBER
  );
```

DML used to test:

```
INSERT INTO lv_data
VALUES      (1,
             'sathya',
             18);

INSERT INTO LEAVE_DATA
VALUES     ('1',
            'sathya',
            SYSDATE,
            SYSDATE + 2,
            NULL,
            NULL);
```